# Pagignation inside modal does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

`{include file="guest/guest-preview.tpl"}` has the table with id = preview_invitees_table

```
 <div class="container">                
        <div id="preview_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">                       
                <div class="modal-content" style="width: 170%;margin-left: -37%;">
                    <div class="modal-header">                                
                        <h4 class="modal-title"><center>招待プレビュー</center></h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">                        
                        {include file="guest/guest-preview.tpl"}
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">                                
                        <div class="bloc button">                            
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-onhover btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">戻る</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

JS

```
 $('#preview_invitees_table').DataTable({ searching: false, "info": false });
```

Comment: where you include the js?

Comment: on page load action

Comment: You need to initialise within guest-previe.tpl. I'm not sure it is possible in tpl file.

Comment: the same code works well if modal is not used and .tpl file is included on the page itself

Comment: Then you can include js in model